# I have created a site in aimeos setup by using artisan: <sitename>... on local host, how can I define its route and access that file?

Tags: php, laravel-5

[admin panel for super admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnj4o.png)

[Accessing myshop2 site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV3kv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is too broad for SO, and it is likely to be closed unless you edit it and narrow it down to a specific problem you are having.  Rather than post screenshots, describe what you've done and show us excerpts of the *relevant* code.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adapt your Aimeos routes for multiple shops:
https://aimeos.org/docs/Laravel/Configure_multiple_shops

Comment: can u explain with  example?